# Configuring a Context specific Tomcat Security Realm

Tags: java, security, tomcat

I am trying to get a context specific security Realm in Tomcat 6.0, but when I start Tomcat I get the following error:

```
09-Dec-2010 16:12:40 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig validateSecurityRoles
INFO: WARNING: Security role name myrole used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
```

I have created the following context.xml file:

```
<Context debug="0" reloadable="true">

  <Resource name="MyUserDatabase"
            type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
            description="User database that can be updated and saved"
            factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
            pathname="conf/my-users.xml" />

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="MyUserDatabase"/>

</Context>
```

Created a file: my-users.xml which I have placed under WEB-INF/conf which contains the following:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="myrole"/>
  <user username="test" password="changeit" roles="myrole" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Added the following lines to my web.xml file:

```
<web-app ...>
  ...
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection> 
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>myrole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
  ...
</web-app>
```

But seem to get the error wherever I put conf/my-users.xml.  Do I have to specify an explicit PATH in the pathname or is it relative to somewhere?  Ideally I would like to have it packaged up as part of my WAR file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need the following in your web.xml

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>myrole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

in order to define the role. Also, I think that you will need to reference the realm in the  login-config

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MyUserDatabase</realm-name>
 </login-config>
```

or similar.

Comment: Hi stjohnroe, That's certainly helped and had cleared the startup error, however it appears that Tomcat is completely ignoring my context.xml file.  If I add &lt;role rolename="myrole"/&gt;    &lt;user username="test" password="changeit" roles="myrole" /&gt; to $catalina.home/conf/tomcat-users.xml then it works, but I want a custom tomcat-users file.  Any ideas or is it not possible to have two realms?

Comment: I would create it as a separate realm, changing the path and resourceName/name properties, this should allow you to reference it as a separate realm.

Comment: I would add: don't use BASIC authentication, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180206/how-to-force-jetty-to-ask-for-credentials-after-invalidating-the-session

Comment: realm-name is not important here - when using BASIC. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10892336/539394

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `tomcat-users.xml` file in your Tomcat configuration directory that defines security roles as an example of what you need.

Also, refer to the following [article](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html) for guidance.