# Realm name in tomcat (web.xml)

Tags: tomcat, security, web.xml

What is the realm-name in the tomcat.

```
<login-config> 
     <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method> 
     <realm-name></realm-name> 
</login-config>
```

In the above code I have to fill the realm-name element. I have seen the following code in the server.xml file:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" 
            resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
```

Where is the realm-name specified? Is it the user name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Realm name is not the user name. It is the authentication realm, 'typically a description of the computer or system being accessed" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication. This should be name that makes sense for the resource you are protecting.

Comment: It's basically something you make up. It doesn't have to match anything, it should just make sense for your application.

Answer (score 10):

The value `<realm-name>` element is used to calculate the digested value of a cleartext password, as described here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Digested_Passwords

If `<realm-name>` element is not specified in web.xml, the default value of "`Authentication required`" is used.