# How to setup authentication mechanism in solr 7?

Tags: apache, solr

I have installed solr 7.7 standalone in my production server. I am trying to setup authentication mechanism using jetty approach. This is what I tried:

1.modified “/opt/solr/server/etc/jetty.xml

```
<Call name="addBean">
 <Arg>
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
   <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
   <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
   <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
  </New>
 </Arg> 
</Call>
```

2. created credentials file in /opt/solr/server/etc/realm.properties

   ```
   admin: admin123,core
   ```
3. modified /opt/solr/server/etc/webdefault.xml

   ```
   <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>core</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
   </login-config>
   ```

After this If I restart solr service, solr is not getting started. In the logs I am getting error as:

```
 Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: refreshInterval
 Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: TYPE
 Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService.setRefreshInterval(java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not [using the built-in authentication](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/basic-authentication-plugin.html)?

Comment: I was creating security.json in wrong place. That's why it was not working. Now I am able to get it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create Security file:`sudo vim /var/solr/data/security.json`

```
{
"authentication":{
   "blockUnknown": true,
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}],
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
}}
```

This will create user called "solr" with password SolrRocks

Then Restart solr service:`sudo service solr restart`

Verification:`http://<ip_address>:8983/solr/admin/authentication`

Comment: great solution that still works with solr 8.6.x. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

refreshInterval did not work as the method has been deprecated in favor of setHotReload (boolean) in recent versions of Jetty.

https://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/security/HashLoginService.html#setRefreshInterval-int-

Solr 7.7 uses Jetty 9.4.14.v20181114

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_4_1/changes/Changes.html#v7.7.0.versions_of_major_components

You can use the following in jett.xml, if you still want to try this instead of [BasicAuthPlugin](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/basic-authentication-plugin.html) -

```
    <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
          <Set name="name">Login Required</Set>
          <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
          <Set name="HotReload">false</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
</Call>
```

By the way, this procedure has some issues since it uses the "BASIC" Authentication of [HashLoginService](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security.html) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180206/how-to-force-jetty-to-ask-for-credentials-with-basic-authentication-after-invali).